# How to build Mahout /usr/lib resource folders after build with Maven

Tags: maven, build, hadoop, mahout, cloudera

I am new to this stuff so I hope someone can help;

I want to build my own Apache Mahout installation from source code. I have Maven2.2.1. Following the instructions on the Mahout wiki I was able to check out the code (Mahout-0.6-SNAPSHOT) and build Mahout with Maven. At least that is was I thought happened after "mvn install" from the root of the folder containing the checked out src code. Test were run, which took a while. 
So I now have all these jars (called artifacts if Im not mistaking) in a Maven repository on ~/.m2/repository.

So my first question now is; how do I get from here to a 'installed' package like I am used to when I run a RPM on redhat. By that I mean a new folder under /usr/lib/ and from there a /lib a /bin etc. folder.

Second question is about dependency jars. I can see in the repository that Mahout was built with a hadoop-core-0.20.204.0.jar but that is not the jar I want because I run a Hadoop cluster with another hadoop-core jar from Cloudera. How would I go about to build Mahout again with the right hadoop-core jar? Or would it just be a matter of changing one hadoop-core jar for another in the /lib folder being created (after my first question is answered)

Thanks